# Downloading files must have a url in the anchor for mac

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an officejs add-in for excel. Part of the add-in the user is able to download an .xlsx(m) file and open it. I found that on windows I can have a button that is able to point the user's browser to the right spot. On Macs however, is there any other way to download a file, than to have the url be in the anchor html the user clicks on?

Comment: Given that an add-in runs within the context of an Excel file, I'm sure I understand what you're doing here. Are you looking to insert additional content into the current Excel file?

Comment: The add-in works with existing excel files which already have formatting, tables, formulas, etc.

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-JavaScript-FileDownload

Answer (score 0):

My team found two solutions. One was to make the link styled as the desired html element, and then use javascript to change the URL as needed. The other option was to create a link in memory and then create a click event on it

```
var _link = document.createElement('a');
                    _link.setAttribute('href', url);
                    _link.target = '_blank';
                    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                    event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                    _link.dispatchEvent(event);
```